# Which map is the most efficient for coins and gems in Temple Run 2

Tags: temple-run-2

Which of the three maps:

1.original Sky Summit

2.next Frozen Shadows

3.current Blazing Sands

is the most efficient for collecting coins and gems for a fixed amount of time playing?

They all seem to have pluses and minuses in terms of efficiency per time and distance but I am wondering if anyone who plays a lot has already done experiments before I try some of my own.

Comment: As far as characters, for coins only, playing with Usain Bolt with the bolt powerup seems like the best plan, but if using the gem power to maximize gems per time played that could be with any character.

Answer (score 1):

Sky summit gives constant coins and diamonds. 
Blazing sands is more difficult but seems to give preferably one type of item per game: more gems or more powerups or chests. It is however more fun and you get hints about your next turn, if you pay attention.  Good luck!